# Array[element+1] returns undefined?

Tags: javascript, arrays, undefined

I'm trying to check whether a given element in an array is bigger than it's two adjacent elements, but array[element+1] returns - undefined. However when I try with array1[(element-1)+2] it works just fine.

This is the array:

```
var array1 = [1, 5, 56, 6, 7, 8, 12, 5, 1];
```

And my Code:

```
function biggestOfThree(element){
    if((element == 0)||(element == array1Length-1)){
        document.write("There aren't 2 adjacent elements in the array");
    }
    else{
        if((array1[element]>array1[element+1])&&(array1[element]>array1[element-1])){
            document.write(array1[element] + " is bigger than it's adjacent elements")
        }
        else{
            document.write(array1[element] + " isn't bigger than it's adjacent elements")
        }
    }

}
```

...and the function for receiving the element by the user:

```
function assign(){
var i_element = document.getElementById('indexOfTheElement');
var i = i_element.value;
    biggestOfThree(i)
}
```

Comment: Where does `array1Length` get defined?

Comment: You did mean to write *array1[element+1] returns - undefined* right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error you see is due to JavaScript's **dynamic typing**. Use **[parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)**

```
var i = parseInt(i_element.value);
```

The `+ 1` still regards it a string and appends 1 to it. Performing a `-1` forces it to consider it an int. Hence your results. Always convert to int using `parseInt()`

```
"1" + 1 = 11
"1" - 1 = 0
```

As @Elias said, it is best to define the radix when using parseInt.

```
parseInt(string, 10)
                  ^ radix
```

Comment: Be careful with `parseInt` and leading zeroes. Best coerce to a number like so `i = +(i_element.value);` or `parseInt(i_element.value,10)`